# multiple where clause in sql

Tags: mysql, inner-join, where-clause

I don't know if this is possible but i will give this a try.

I have 3 tables:

First table: (sender_id and receiver_id is a foreign key referencing to loginportal table)

```
messages
sender_id | receiver_id | message
    3     |      1      |   ...
```

Second Table: (req_id is  a foreign key referencing request table)

```
loginportal
loginPortal_id | username | req_id
     1         |   admin  |    1
     3         |    user  |    2
```

Third table:

```
request
req_id | firstname | surname
   1   |    john   |   doe
   2   |    jane   |   me
```

Problem:

Whenever i used this query:

```
"SELECT id, message_sender_id, 
        message_title, message_body, sent_date, message_status,
        username, firstname, surname
        FROM messages m
        INNER JOIN loginportal l
        INNER JOIN request r
        ON m.message_receiver_id= l.loginPortal_id
        AND l.req_id=r.req_id
        WHERE m.message_receiver_id=(
        SELECT loginPortal_id FROM loginportal 
        WHERE username='".$_SESSION['user']."')";
```

What i got is the receiver username and receiver firstname and surname.
What i want is i will have the receiver username but SENDER's firstname and surname. is this possible?

Comment: You don't want to accept arbitrary user input in your SQL Query.  In your case, you really don't want a user that has the name `--; DROP TABLE USERS;`, do you?  Use PHP best practices; and, parameterize your queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a message_id field, then combine two subqueries finding the sender and reciever info on their new message_id. Something along these lines...haven't tested it

```
SELECT query1.username, query2.firstname, query2.surname

FROM (SELECT username, message_id FROM loginportal, messages WHERE loginPortal_id = receiver_id) AS query1,
(SELECT firstname, surname, message_id FROM request, loginportal, messages WHERE request.req_id = loginportal_req.id AND loginportal.loginPortal_id = messages.sender_id) AS query2

WHERE query1.message_id = query2.message_id;
```